# What's the difference between Net cash provided by operating activities and Operating cash flow?

Tags: financial-statements

I'm confused by these two terms, they have the same number in the statement of cash flow, I wonder if there is any difference between them.

Comment: It isn't related to personal finance per se. OP might need to frame it better. These are basic financial statement questions, can be got from a book on such.

Answer (score 1):

The two terms are synonymous.

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cash-flow-from-operating-activities.asp

> Also called operating cash flow or net cash from operating activities, it can be calculated as follows:
>
> Cash Flow From Operating Activities = EBIT + Depreciation - Taxes